Unique elements in a Python list using "set"
"""
arr = map(int, input().split())
arr1=list(arr)
print(f"My list:" + str(arr1))
print(f"After sorting in reverse order:" + str(arr1))
arr1.sort(reverse=True)
unique_list = list(set(arr1))
print(f"Second element after making list unique:" + str(unique_list[1]))

"""
Wrote this code, In order to get the 2nd highest element from a list of unique numbers, It doesn't seem to get me the right results, What might be the possible issue here ?
I'm expecting it would print me the 2nd highest number/integer from the result.

Sets are unordered collections

Using set does not preserve the order of the input list.  You need to sort the set.
unique_list = sorted(set(arr1))
print("Second element after making list unique:", unique_list[-2])


Sets are unordered, so list(set(...)) loses the ordering of ....
You'll want sorted(set(...), reverse=True) to turn the set of unique values into a reverse-sorted list.
